# Binary Associations between PHP Classes

Tags: php, oop

Hi everyone I have two classes a User and a Shopping cart which model a binary association between them. In Order to implement it i have created two classes

A User class:

```
class User{
    protected $name ;
    protected $email;
    protected $shoppingCart;

    public function __construct($name , $email)
    {
        $this->name =$name;
        $this ->email =$email;
        $this->shoppingCart=new ShoppingCart($this);
    }

    //other getter and setter functions
}

class ShoppingCart{
    //Array stores the list of products in the cart:
    protected  $products = array();

    // For storing the IDs, as a convenience:
    protected $ids = array();

    // protected user    
    protected $user;

    // Constructor just sets the object up for usage:    
    function __construct($user) {
        $this->products = array();
        $this->ids = array();
        $this->user =$user;
    }

    // functions to add or delete item    
}
```

My Question is , is it ok for both user class and Shopping cart class to have an instance of each other so when I construct user , i construct its shopping cart in its constructor. and when i construct the shopping cart , I pass the user infor in the shopping carts constructor to assign the shopping cart to the user.

How can i model this association properly. Also i would have to access the users shopping cart to display its total price from main PHP script...in that case can i also make the ShoppingCart attribute of Users Class public

Comment: There's no reason for `ShoppingCart` to have an instance of the user since you already know what user it belongs to (since it is in the user object). You won't even be able to access the Shopping cart without having access to the user object.

Answer (score -1):

Circular dependencies *can* cause a number of frustration. Serialization gets complicated, deep cloning is weird and PHP needs to do more work to garbage collect it.

That being said, if you are aware of those side-effects, circular dependencies can work just fine. Other examples that exist in the wild is for example the javascript DOM, where every element has a reference to its children, and every child a reference to its parent.

I disagree with the commenter saying:

> There's no reason for ShoppingCart to have an instance of the user since you already know what user it belongs to (since it is in the user object). You won't even be able to access the Shopping cart without having access to the user object.

This might be true in some cases, but not universally. I would agree though that it's slightly better to design it differently, if all things are equal.